# VBscript , create directory in FTP

Tags: vbscript, upload, ftp, directory

I would like to create a directory in FTP, the name of the directory must be as my computer name,

here is my code,

```
Dim FoldertoCreate, filesys, newfolder, Ob
Set Ob = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Network" )
FoldertoCreate = "ftp://user:password@ftpserver/url-path/" & ob.ComputerName
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not filesys.FolderExists(FoldertoCreate) Then
   Set newfolder = filesys.CreateFolder(FoldertoCreate)
End If
```

This code doesn't work however when i replace ftp://user:password@ftpserver/url-path with any local directory like D:/ , it works :S

how to make it work for my ftp too

Comment: Scripting.FileSystemObject is for file systems, it does not support FTP.

Comment: so what do i use ? could you please tell me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FileSystemObject does not support FTP.  The Shell Automation Object does, but it doesn't seem to like the NewFolder method.  That leaves us with automating the FTP.exe command using an unattended FTP session.  It might look something like this.

```
strUser = "myusername"
strPass = "mypassword"
strHost = "ftp.myhost.com"

Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFso.OpenTextFile("session.txt", ForWriting, vbTrue)

With objFile
    .WriteLine "OPEN " & strHost
    .WriteLine "USER " & strUser
    .WriteLine strPass
    .WriteLine "mkdir sometestdirectory"
    .Close
End With

strFTP = "%systemroot%\System32\ftp.exe -s:session.txt"
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strFTP = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(strFTP)
WshShell.Run strFTP,, vbTrue

objFso.DeleteFile "session.txt", vbTrue
```

Comment: this is not wokrng with my ip

Comment: Have you made sure that strUser, strPass, and strHost contain the proper credentials?  Did you get any error?

Comment: Where do you use the strHost variable? It is defined but not used anywhere else.

Comment: @anilca Very sorry about that. I corrected the code sample. Notice the "OPEN" line.

Comment: Thanks @Nilpo. And I think that .WriteLine strPassword line has to be .WriteLine strPass

Comment: @Nilpo or .WriteLine "PASS " & strPass? I tried both but I'm getting login failed error.

Comment: @anilca Try removing the `"USER" &` portion. It may be prompting you for the user so the USER command is not needed. Same with `"PASS " &`.