# creating a folder in FTP server

Tags: vbscript, ftp, directory

I had to create a folder in FTP server using VBScript. Now I can save the local file in my machine to a folder in FTP server. But I have to create a folder in FTP using VBScript code and should save the local file to that folder. Can anyone help me solve this issue? The code I used is given below.

```
Set objFSO = Wscript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
path ="D:\imgs\images (2).jpg"

FTPUpload(path)

Sub FTPUpload(path)
  Const copyType = 16
  waitTime = 10000
  FTPUser = "ftp_username"
  FTPPass = "ftp_password"
  FTPHost = "ipaddress"
  FTPDir = "/ftpDirectory/" 
  strFTP = "ftp://" & FTPUser & ":" & FTPPass & "@" & FTPHost & FTPDir
  Set objFTP = oShell.NameSpace(strFTP)
  If objFSO.FileExists(path) Then
    Set objFile = objFSO.getFile(path)
    strParent = objFile.ParentFolder
    Set objFolder = oShell.NameSpace(strParent)
    Set objItem = objFolder.ParseName(objFile.Name)
    WScript.Echo "Uploading file " & objItem.Name & " to " & strFTP
    objFTP.CopyHere objItem, copyType
  End If
  'WScript.Echo "Uploaded Successfully"
```

Comment: This was already answered in this post. [VBscript , create directory in FTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332694/vbscript-create-directory-in-ftp)